# Is there a $k$ where $0\leq k\leq n$ such that $\log_2 {n\choose k}>\frac{1}{2} n$ for large $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, discrete-mathematics

My question is that : Is there an integer $k$ where $0\leq k\leq n$ such that $\log_2{n\choose k }> \frac{1}{2} n$ for large $n$?

In addition, we require that to find a $k$ such that
${n\choose k }$ $>$ $2^{(\frac{1}{2}+ \alpha )\times n}$ for some $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: Yes, for example, $k=\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor$ will definitely work since $$
\binom{n}{\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor} \sim \frac{{2^{n + 1/2} }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}.
$$

Comment: Do not modify the question by adding a new problem to it hours after the original was answered and accepted. Ask a new question indeed and also show your effort in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $@$Gary's $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ the given inequality can be expressed as
\begin{equation*}
 \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}>2^{n/2}.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}

This is an elementary proof of $(1)$ not only for large $n$ but for all integers $n\ge 3.$
If $n$ is even we have to prove that

\begin{equation*}
 \binom{2n}{n}>2^{n}\quad \text{ for } n\ge 2.\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
In
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

we find the the formula
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}}^{2}=\binom{2n}{n}.\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
We borrow the argument

''Suppose you have $2n$ empty squares arranged in a row and you want to mark (select) $n$ of them. There are $\binom{2n}{n}$  ways to do this. On the other hand, you may select your $n$ squares by selecting $k$ squares from among the first $n$ and $n-k$  squares from the remaining $n$ squares; any $k$ from $0$ to $n$ will work. This gives ''
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{2n}{n}.\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
But
\begin{equation*}
 \binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}
\end{equation*}
and $(3)$ is proved.

If $n\ge 2$ there is some $k$ for which $\binom{n}{k}>1$.
Consequently
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}}^{2}>\sum_{k=0}^{n}1\cdot\binom{n}{k}=2^{n}
\end{equation*}
and $(2)$ is proved.

In the odd case we have to prove that
\begin{equation*}
 \binom{2n+1}{n}>2^{n+1/2}\quad \text{ for } n\ge 1.\tag{4}
\end{equation*}
However,
\begin{equation*}
 \binom{2n+1}{n}=\dfrac{2n+1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}>\sqrt{2}\cdot2^n=2^{n+1/2}
\end{equation*}
and $(4)$ is also proved.